# How to create a file alias in iOS?

Tags: ios, unix, ios5, alias, nsfilemanager

In order to support UIDocumentController options on different file types, I thought that perhaps creating and pointing to a file alias would be a good solution. The file is large, so copying the file and duplicating it would create some overhead. Is there a way to point to the original file, but under a different name/extension, like a Finder alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using hard links.

To create them, take a look at `linkItemAtURL:toURL:error:` and `linkItemAtPath:toPath:error:` in `NSFileManager`.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Could not find it in the docs.